# wrong result of total nodes in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have the following program which creates a simple linked list of chars.

```
typedef struct letter{
    char c;
    struct letter *next;
}letter;


 int count(letter *c){
    int n = 0;
    letter *t = c;
    while(t){
        n++;
        t = t->next;
    }
    t = NULL;
    return n;
}
int main(){
    letter *head = (letter*)malloc(sizeof(letter));
    letter *cur = head;
    int n;
    printf("Give me a number:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n > 0){
        printf("Give me a char:");
        scanf(" %c",&cur->c);
        cur->next = (letter*)malloc(sizeof(letter));
        cur=cur->next;
        cur->next = NULL;
        printf("Give me a number:");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }

    cur = head;

    printf("Total nodes: %d",count(head));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I am filling the list with characters until the user presses 0.The problem is that when I try to output the total number of nodes using count() function I get wrong result.For example consider the following input:

```
1
a
2
b
3
c
0
```

the result is:

```
Total nodes:4
```

which is wrong. It should be `Total nodes:3`

Can you explain why this is happening?

Comment: `while(t){
        n++;
    }` is an *infinite loop* if `t` is nonzero.

Comment: @EOF sorry copy paste mistake

Comment: I'd recommend stepping through the program with a debugger. Start by focusing on what happens when you enter `0` as the first number. (Hint: Undefined behavior by dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.)

Answer (score 0):

When you create the list you also create the first node, but you never assign its `char` a value.

I have two suggestions on how to fix your problem:

1. Don't count the first node. Always skip it when retrieving values or counting list length. This is slightly easier to implement, IMO.

or

2. Let the head point to `NULL` when the list is empty. Not that this solution means that the head pointer changes it's value when you insert the first element, so you need to pass the list pointer by reference to your insert/delete functions.

Comment: Why does he create the first node when he creates the list?

Comment: @cssGEEK He allocates a `letter` when the head is created. The `next` poointer is assigned `NULL` and the `c` member isn't assigned at all. A call to `count(head)` before inserting any node will return `1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cur->next = (letter*)malloc(sizeof(letter));
cur=cur->next;
cur->next = NULL;
```

This code will create a node every time loop executes, so after 3rd char entry, node will be created without containing any value.
so in count loop it will result in 4 nodes.

Modified Loop: Run and check

```
while(n > 0){
        printf("Give me a char:");
        scanf(" %c",&cur->c);
        cur->next = NULL;
        printf("Give me a number:");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if(n > 0)
        {
           cur->next = (letter*)malloc(sizeof(letter));
           cur=cur->next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I thought so too, but then I read the code more carefully. This is not what is happening.